# Pie Chart is not coming with dynamic data in HIghChart

Tags: javascript, json, charts, highcharts

I am making a pie chart with json data but pie chart is not coming with data backend data.I am generating the data with this format which is actually the format given by HighCharts.I am pasting my code

```
function createChart(array){
//alert(array);
 var arrJobName = [];
var arrRevenue = [];

for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    searchResultArray = array[i].split("$$##$$##");   

    //var label = '\''+ searchResultArray[1]+ '\'';
    //var value = parseInt(searchResultArray[5]);

    //arrJobName.push(searchResultArray[1]);
    //arrRevenue.push(parseInt(searchResultArray[5]));
    //alert(parseFloat(searchResultArray[5]))
    // arrRevenue.push(['\''+ searchResultArray[1]+ '\'',""(parseFloat(searchResultArray[5]))]);

    arrRevenue.push('['+searchResultArray[1]+","+parseFloat(searchResultArray[5])+']');

}

alert(arrRevenue)
//

$(function () {
    $('.containerForDiagram').highcharts({
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2014'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                    style: {
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Job By Revenue',
            data: [

                    [arrRevenue]
//['Director - Inventory/Planning Systems',36800],['DevOps Engineer',20000],   ['Java Developer',0],['Software Development Manager',0],['Sr. Business Analyst / Oracle Functional',0],['Product Manager Native Advertising',0],['Corporate Recruiter ',26000],['Sr. Oracle Supply Chain BA',0],['Network Engineer',0],['Sharepoint Programmer Analyst',0],['Commercial Manager -  Mexico',0],['Commercial Manager Colombia',0],['Sr. Global Architect - End User Computing',29900],['Head of Marketing   Peru',0],['Director, Sr Attorney',0]

this is the data i am getting with my code                  ]


        }]
    });
});

}
```

The data i am getting for the arrRevenue is given here.But the arrRevenue is not working when i am using it dynamically.I have tried all syntax.But no use still .Somebody please help.

Comment: Two things: 1) all number should be numbers, for example: `"2"` is a string. 2) `arrRevenue.push('['+ ... ']')` is generating string. You want to use arrays. I advice you to go to MDN (mozilla dev network) and start with reading tutorials about JS.

Comment: @PawełFus then how i will make that format ['Level',12]  with the data??

Comment: Something like this: `data: arrRevenue`, where `arrRevenue` is made like this: `arrRevenue.push( [ searchResultArray[1], parseFloat(searchResultArray[5]) ] );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with generating data. Required are two changes:

- data assignment: `data: [arrRevenue]` -> `data: arrRevenue`
- data generation: `arrRevenue.push('['+searchResultArray[1]+","+parseFloat(searchResultArray[5])+']');` -> `arrRevenue.push( [ searchResultArray[1], parseFloat(searchResultArray[5]) ] );`